# Python - Using objects in different classes

Tags: python

How can I use objects which belong to one class, in another different class? I tried different things, but I still do not get a solution. Let´s say I have the following example code:

```
class ClassA():
    def __init__(self):
        print "I am ClassA"

    def methodA(self):
        print "Method executed"
    
class ClassB():
    def __init__(self):
        print "I am ClassB"
    
        self.varB = 0       

    def methodB(self):       
        if self.varB == 0:
            # Error here
            self.objectA.methodA()
        else:
            print "Method not executed"

class ClassC():
    def __init__(self):
        print "I am ClassC"
    
        self.objectA = ClassA()
        self.objectA.methodA()


#Step 1:
obj1 = ClassC()

#Step 2:
obj2 = ClassB()    

#Step 3: (Gives error)
obj2 = methodB()
```

In this example, I have three classes. In `ClassC`, I create an instance of `ClassA`, which is used to execute the respective method (`methodA`). If afterwards we procceed with "Step 1", the output is:

> I am ClassC
>
> I am ClassA
>
> Method executed

Then, in "Step 2", I create a new object of `ClassB`. Following to the last output, we get now as well:

> I am ClassB

The problems comes with "Step 3", when I execute the `methodB` for the last object. The error:

> AttributeError: ClassB instance has no attribute 'objectA'

I have very clear the origin of the error. I can´t simply use the instance that I created in `ClassC`, inside the method of `ClassB`.

Does anyone know, how could I access from `ClassB`, an instance (in this case `objectA`) that I created in other class (`ClassC`)?

Comment: You should use new style classes in python 2: inherit from object: `class A(object):` or better yet, python 3... That said, you cannot do what you intend to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `objectA` belongs to a specific instance of class C. So, there is no way, you *have to* pass this instance to the instance of class B somehow. The way you are using it, probably in the constructor of class B:

```
def __init__(self, c):
    print "I am ClassB"
    self.varB = 0   
    self.objectA = c.objectA
```

and then

```
obj2 = ClassB(obj1)
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, and it makes all the sense of the world. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try Inheritance in Python. Inherit Class A in Class B.

```
class ClassB(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print "I am ClassB"
        self.varB = 0       

    def methodB(self):       
        if self.varB == 0:
            # Error here
            self.methodA()
        else:
            print "Method not executed"
```

This should work for you.